# Getting class not found exception when trying to use external jar in yarn cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use an external jar in my code. It is working fine in my local eclipse set-up as I have added the jar as Referenced Libraries, however when I try to create a Jar of my code and deploy it in Azure Data Factory - Spark Activity, it is not able to get the external jar in cluster(driver-node or executor-node) I am not sure.

I have created the spark session as below :-

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("test_cluster")
.master("yarn")
.getOrCreate()
```

And I have added the external Jar later in code as below :-

```
spark.sparkContext.addJar(jarPath)
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jarPath)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", jarPath)
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong as I am getting the below error message :-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source
```

Comment: Make your application jar fat in case for some reason you are not able to get classpath of spark. Also to spark submit you can pass --jars param.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried creating Runnable/Fat Jar but as I am not getting any drop-down option in Launch Configuration therefore Finish option is not available.